# Porting TcpClient based HTTP client to Windows Store and Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, http, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am building a Windows 8 'Metro' client for a home control system that supports a bastardization of HTTP as its protocol. I cannot use `WebClient` for this because I need to keep the socket open and do multiple pseudo-HTTP operations on it.

The protocol the server speaks is very simple and very immutable. It's an ancient piece of software and will never change. So my client code can (and has to) be hard-coded to its peculiar ways.

I've successfully built this using `TcpClient` in a console app. I'm now porting it to Win8/Windows Phone and now know `TcpClient` is not available. Duh.

I can't use the ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries because that `HttpClient` does not appear to let me have finer control over the socket either.

So I am stuck with `Windows.Networking.Sockets`. Below is my current code (based on `TcpClient`. This code runs on a separate thread. As I said, it works great in my C# console app.

```
private void ReadSubscriptionResponses()
{
    // Process the response.
    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(_subscriptionClient.GetStream());
    int contentLength;
    int hashCode = 0;

    // From here on we will get responses on the stream that
    // look like HTTP POST responses.
    while (!rdr.EndOfStream) {
        var line = rdr.ReadLine();
        Debug.WriteLine(line);

        if (line.StartsWith("HTTP/1.1 404 ")) {
            string error = line.Substring("HTTP/1.1 404 ".Length);
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
            LastStatusCode = "404";
            ParseErrorResponse();
            continue;
        }
        LastStatusCode = "200";

        if (line.StartsWith("Target-Element: ")) {
            string ID = line.Substring("Target-Element: ".Length);
            if (!int.TryParse(ID, out hashCode)) {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: Target-Element: is not an integer.");
            }
        }

        // Content-Length: is always the last HTTP header Premise sends
        if (!line.StartsWith("Content-Length: ") ||
            !int.TryParse(line.Substring("Content-Length: ".Length), out contentLength)) continue;

        if (rdr.EndOfStream) continue;

        // Read the blank line that always follows Content-Length:
        line = rdr.ReadLine();
        Debug.WriteLine(line);

        if (rdr.EndOfStream) continue;

        // Read content
        char[] buffer = new char[contentLength];
        rdr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, contentLength);
        line = new string(buffer);

        // Send line to our caller ...
    }
}
```

This loop is simple because it is based on `StreamReader.EndOfLine` and `StreamReader.ReadLine`.

I was hoping that `Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket` would provide similar functionality, but there is no `EndOfStream` or `ReadLine` in `DataReader`. Can someone point me at an example of using `StreamSocket` that I could fit in here.

I really want to keep this code as portable as possible so I can run it on multiple platforms.

Comment: I'm not sure what features you're using from `TcpClient` but there's a library that implements some of it for WP that might help https://github.com/mikoskinen/socketex

Comment: UnconsumedBufferLength? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.unconsumedbufferlength.aspx